# How can I draw circle in html5 canvas as an individual canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working on an HTML5 project.
In that, I am getting problem in drawing circle. I have canvas on which image is loaded. And when I am going to draw a circle, I am creating a new canvas (dynamically) inside which I want to draw circle. But Circle is not drawing correctly.
How can I get out from this problem?

**EDIT:-**

Drawing Code is as follow:-

```
getMouse(e);
x2=mx; y2=my;
var width=x2-x1;
var height=y2-y1;
annCanvas.style.position = "absolute";

annCanvas.style.left=""+x1+"px";
annCanvas.style.top=""+y1+"px";
annCanvas.width=width+4;
annCanvas.height=height+4;
annCanvas.style.zIndex="100000";

document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(annCanvas);

var kappa = .5522848;
 ox = ((width) / 2) * kappa, // control point offset horizontal
 oy = ((height) / 2) * kappa, // control point offset vertical
 xe =(width),           // x-end
 ye =(height),           // y-end
 xm = (width)/ 2,       // x-middle
 ym =  (height) / 2;       // y-middle
 annCanvasContext=annCanvas.getContext('2d');
 annCanvasContext.beginPath();
 annCanvasContext.lineWidth=4;
 annCanvasContext.moveTo(2, ym);
 annCanvasContext.bezierCurveTo(2, ym - oy, xm - ox, 2, xm, 2);
 annCanvasContext.bezierCurveTo(xm + ox, 2, xe, ym - oy, xe, ym);
 annCanvasContext.bezierCurveTo(xe, ym + oy, xm + ox, ye, xm, ye);
 annCanvasContext.bezierCurveTo(xm - ox, ye, 2, ym + oy, 2, ym);
 annCanvasContext.closePath();
 annCanvasContext.stroke();
```

If i change lineWidth to 10 or 15, it gets different shape instead of circle.

Comment: provide some code, or better specify your problem..what does it mean "not drawing correctly"?

Comment: Jeremy and Simekadam:- "not drawing correctly means" its shape gets change when we are changing its border width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: Sir I have tried it but i want to draw circle inside a separate canvas. For every circle drawing at run time, circle will draw inside a new canvas as i mentioned above.

Comment: yes bt you can use above logic and draw circle inside a new canvas element and append it!!! i guess most of the logic for creating a new canvas and appending it is already with you!! why dont you append your logic and mine????

Comment: Thanks.I have merged your and mine logic.It is working but it gets problem in increasing my canvas size and circle radius at runtime(mouse move). how can i solve it.